# I want to close statement automatically

Tags: java, spring

I want to close statements automatically.

I want to achieve it using the technology of the following packages:

- Java 1.5
- Spring framework 2.5

It seems not to close statements automatically in the default settings, though I think that the transaction manager of Spring automatically shuts statements.

I do not want to call `close()` of statement as much as possible in the method for maintainability.

Is there a method to ensure that the statement's closed?
The amount of coding increases if coming for all the methods to have to call close() of statement, and there is a problem that the possibility that the omission is generated goes out.

Moreover, I am making the framework. It wants to make the restriction as much as possible by such a reason and to make a little method.

Moreover, is there an official site or document that shows the reason when there is no closing method?
I'm Japanese, so please explain using simple statements.

Comment: `close()` what? You question is woefully incomprehensible.

Comment: All I've seen from Jarrod Roberson is cranky comments and not a single answer.  Do you do more than hang around here and nitpick other people's stuff, or do you actually provide answers?

Comment: @duffymo - He could try the [your foreign language here] equivalent of StackOverflow and see how he does.  The OP obviously isn't a native speaker.

Comment: @Ed Staub - I'm not the one who complained about the question being incomprehensible.  That was Jarrod Roberson.  Please re-read or correct my misunderstanding.

Comment: @duffymo - Sorry, wasn't clear.  I was suggesting _Jarrod_ try asking technical questions in a language he doesn't know well, and see what he gets back.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Spring will handle all this for you if you use the SimpleJdbcTemplate.  I'd recommend it highly.

The Spring transaction manager is *not* closing the statement.  That's a separate concern.  After all, you'd still want the statement closed even if you didn't have an open transaction.

I would not write your own framework.  I would bet that you'd be hard-pressed to improve on what Spring 2.5 is already giving you.  Perhaps it's more a matter of training and understanding Spring's capabilities better.